# How ISP limits the speeds?

Tags: internet, isp, internet-speed

Technically I can enjoy the maximum internet data speed, but ISP will only allowed the set limit, how does ISP does that? And how does it do it for both uplink and downlink?

1. Does it set max limit to the data sent/received in 1 second and drops the rest of the packets. Uplink packets can be dropped without much issue, but dropping downlink packets is very inefficient.
2. Does it stores the packets, and only sends them after a delay. But this creates non-needed load on the ISP.
3. Something else?

And, how can we use it to our advantage, given that there is ping latency of around 100ms.

Comment: This will depend on the equipment used by your ISP... dropped packets are unlikely.

Comment: You cannot do what you want without paying for the service.

Answer (score 1):

This will be slightly different for each ISP & data-link type. Basically, the setup is configured by a file sent from their end to your modem/router. You cannot access it directly to view or modify it, though you may be able to see the structure enabled by it.
Any attempt to modify the structure will result in it failing to connect.

Here's an abbreviated form of what you are allowed to inspect on my system, which is a Docsis 3.0 fibre connection. Even though it might seem 'fast' it's speed limited to less than half what Docsis 3.0 is capable of.

[image]

Those data rates are controlled by the config .cm file. That's 400mbps down & 38mbps up.

Comment: It's highly unlikely this is enforced client-side, that could be easily circumvented.

Comment: @DanielB - how so? There's no way in for the user. You get presented a web front-end, no way behind it from 'inside the building' only from the ISP's end. That's as basic as not allowing router/gateway admin over wifi. Wrong connection, no admin. In the UK you can't even use your own modem. You can't move a modem from one cable connection to another. Any 'change' in the system just locks the device out. You need an engineer & a phone call to get it reconnected.

Comment: The configuration you present is only about the link speed. Certainly, for ADSL and Cable that is often all that is required, because the negotiated link speed is _also_ enforced on the other side. However, with wireless links and maybe even dynamic limits (like when the traffic quota is used up) this isn’t enough of an explanation, because these are not enforced on the router. There may not even be a router.

Comment: OP is talking about link speed [& naïvely how to bypass it]. I could include how ACKs work, but i don't think that would contribute to understanding, so I just took the broadest 'no you can't do that' approach. My own service used to be controlled entirely at the far end, but is now handled locally [after many years of the ISP forgetting to shift their switch if I changed my service]. If I change my link speed [by up/downgrading my account], the config file changes, as do the traffic rate numbers. The switchover takes seconds, as opposed to days [or months, as alluded to].

Comment: While its 'client' side - the CPEs are managed by the ISP - either via Mac addresses or such, and *most* modern ISPs do retain some control over it. I often find that the best way to understand a system is to know how its built, and this resource on building your own ISP https://startyourownisp.com/posts/network-topology/#gotta-start-somewhere backs up Tetsujin's answer - that its managed on the CPE, and can be tied into the billing system automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, other than a small queue to buffer bursts, traffic will be dropped. Typically you don’t notice, because protocols like TCP or applications higher up the stack will handle this gracefully, for example by retransmitting packets and/or by slowing down the send rate. More sophisticated QoS/traffic shaping methods could use longer queues, but this often comes at a price: Higher latency.

Excess traffic will be dropped wherever the next link is slower, like going from a 100 MBit/s link to a 10 MBit/s link, or where artificial limits are in place.

Artificial limits could be things like throttling your speed because you’ve exceeded the monthly traffic quota, or even server-side limits.

Physical limits are because a link cannot transfer data faster. A simple example is Ethernet. Gigabit is ubiquitous today, but older 100 MBit/s cards were simply incapable of these speeds. With ADSL or Cable it’s a little more complicated, because you could have subscribed to a speed that is lower than the physical limit (like running a 100 MBit/s link on all-Gigabit hardware). The most complicated are wireless links like Wi-Fi or cell networks, with ever-changing conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia describes
[Bandwidth throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling)
this way:

> These bandwidth limitations can be implemented:
>
> - at application software level (a client program or a server program, i.e. ftp server, web server, etc.) which can be run and configured to
>   throttle data sent through network or even to throttle data received
>   from network (by reading data at most at a throttled amount per
>   second);
> - at network management level (typically done by an ISP).
>
> The first one (client/server program) is usually perfectly legal
> because it is a choice of the client manager or the server manager (by
> server administrator) to limit or not to limit the speed of data
> received from remote program via network or the speed of data sent to
> target program (server or client).
>
> The second one (ISP) instead is considered an offense in the USA under
> FCC regulations.

Most ISPs will choose the first method which limits the bandwidth
from the client's side, by simply supplying a throttled internet
modem. This method has the advantage of being both legal, and it
also avoids dropping packets.

The second method involves throttling inside the ISP's
server/switching farm,
by in effect introducing an intermediary relay device which is
intentionally throttled. This method is illegal in some countries,
and it also entails dropped packets which might be problematic
for client satisfaction.